# Silverlight: Restrict RowDetailsTemplate width to it's parent DataGrid's width

Tags: silverlight-3.0, datagrid

I'd like to bind the Width of my RowDetailsTemplate to the Width of my DataGrid, so that the row details are not surrounded with scroll bars.

Here's the problem:
[image]

Notice that the RowDetailsTemplate contains hidden content that must be scrolled into view - which is terrible.  The user must drag the scroll bar at the very bottom bottom of the DataGrid in order to see the rest of the row's details - which is very unintuitive.  I really want the row details to layout its content such that no scrolling is necessary.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Charles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `AreRowDetailsFrozen` property on my `DataGrid` to true solved my problem. Example:

```
<data:DataGrid AreRowDetailsFrozen="True" />
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, what were your values for `ColumnWidth` and `CanUserResizeColumns`?

Answer (score 2):

I did find the solution for a similar problem in WPF, you can find it here: [DataGrid RowDetails Width problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210480/datagrid-rowdetails-width-problem/7847609#7847609)

I don't know if it works in silverlight, but give it a try.

> The answers here felt like a workaround so I did some research and did
>   find the solution on the Telerik forums, since we use their
>   RadGridView. Turned out the solution worked for DataGrid as well.
>
> The key is to set the ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility
>   property to Disabled, see example below.
>
> ```
> <DataGrid ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
> <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
>     <DataTemplate>
>         <Border>
>             <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="{Binding RowDetails}"
>                        TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
>         </Border>
>     </DataTemplate>
> </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate> </DataGrid>
> ```