# C# / WPF - DataGrid - Binding the Width of a TextBox in RowDetails to that of the containing DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, width, rowdetailstemplate

My problem is similar to this one;

- [DataGrid RowDetails Width problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210480/wpf-datagrid-rowdetails-width-problem)

Except I would like row details never to exceed the width of the columns it spans.

```
|--0--|--1--|--2--|--3--|--4--|
|---------Row-Details---------|
```

I have tried `AreRowDetailsFrozen` and this had no effect. I have also tried binding to the parent Grid's actual width (OneWay) but this causes the width to exceed that of my two screens.

Here is my current attempt (simplified);

```
  <Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="Grid" 
              Grid.Row="1" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}"
              IsReadOnly="True"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              ColumnWidth="Auto"
              CanUserResizeColumns="False"
              CanUserResizeRows="False"
              RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"
              AreRowDetailsFrozen="True"
              SelectionUnit="FullRow"
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
           <!-- Begin row details section. -->
           <DataTemplate>
               <TextBox DataContext="{Binding ErrorMessage}" 
                       IsReadOnly="True"
                       Margin="5"
                       BorderBrush="Transparent"
                       ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                       ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       Text="{Binding .}">
               </TextBox>
           </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
   </DataGrid>
  </Grid>
```

This results in the following;

```
|--0--|--1--|--2--|--3--|--4--|
|---------Row-Details are as wide as the longest row in their content ---------|
```

Binding the width of the TextBox to any parent container (Grid, DataGrid, ItemsPresenter):

```
Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}, Path=ActualWidth, Mode=OneWay}"
```

Results in:

```
                              |------Viewable Area-------|
|---- Columns ----|
|---------Row-Details --------------------------------------------------------------|
```

It's very frustrating, I just want the Row Details not to change the width of the DataGrid, is that so much to ask? :)

Answer (score 1):

The only way to accomplish this is to change DataGridRow ControlTemplate. There we can bind row details host width (DataGridDetailsPresenter) to width of cells. For example:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type dg:DataGridRow}" TargetType="{x:Type dg:DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="ValidationErrorTemplate">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate>
          <TextBlock Margin="2,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Red" Text="!" />
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type dg:DataGridRow}">
          <Border x:Name="DGR_Border"
                  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                  SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <dgp:SelectiveScrollingGrid>
              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

              <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
              </Grid.RowDefinitions>

              <dgp:DataGridCellsPresenter x:Name="cellPresenter" Grid.Column="1"
                                         ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}"
                                         SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>

              <dgp:DataGridDetailsPresenter  dgp:SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type dg:DataGrid}}, Path=AreRowDetailsFrozen, Converter={x:Static dg:DataGrid.RowDetailsScrollingConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static dg:SelectiveScrollingOrientation.Vertical}}"
                                            Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
                                            Visibility="{TemplateBinding DetailsVisibility}" Width="{Binding ElementName=cellsPresenter, Path=ActualWidth}"/>

              <dgp:DataGridRowHeader dgp:SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical"  Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                    Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type dg:DataGrid}}, Path=HeadersVisibility, Converter={x:Static dg:DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static dg:DataGridHeadersVisibility.Row}}"/>
            </dgp:SelectiveScrollingGrid>
          </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll wait a short time to see if there is a more concise approach but this is the only viable option I've seen so far. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question here [DataGrid RowDetails Width problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210480/datagrid-rowdetails-width-problem/7847609#7847609)

> The answers here felt like a workaround so I did some research and did
>   find the solution on the Telerik forums, since we use their
>   RadGridView. Turned out the solution worked for DataGrid as well.
>
> The key is to set the ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility
>   property to Disabled, see example below.
>
> ```
> <DataGrid ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
> <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
>     <DataTemplate>
>         <Border>
>             <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="{Binding RowDetails}"
>                        TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
>         </Border>
>     </DataTemplate>
> </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate> </DataGrid>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I've found another way to fix the Problem:

```
private void GridOnLoadingRowDetails(object sender, DataGridRowDetailsEventArgs e)
{
    var dataGridColumnHeadersPresenter = FindVisualChild<DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter>((DataGrid)sender);
    e.DetailsElement.SetBinding(WidthProperty, new Binding("ActualWidth") { Source = dataGridColumnHeadersPresenter });
}
```

This prevents you from using constant values (e.g. '6') - which won't fit, if someone set `DataGrid.RowHeaderWidth` - and Converters.

I've added this to the `DataGrid.LoadingRowDetails` event handler, since I am already tweaking the RowDetails in some other ways.